# Ctrl+Alt+ keyboard shortcuts "steal" Alt+ shortcuts

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

This problem is not new - i know it was present in Windows XP, 7, 8/8.1, and now in 10 (and probably 11 too).

If an app uses Ctrl+Alt+something keyboard shortcut, it disables all Alt+ shortcuts. For example Loom app (https://loom.com) uses Ctrl+Alt+C to make confetti effect appear on screen. But Alt+C makes letter ć, widely used in Polish language. So Looms Ctrl+Alt+C completely disables Alt+C, making writing in polish language a lot harder - c is not the only letter we use with Alt, and Loom is not the only app using Ctrl+Alt shortcuts.

Any ideas how to make it work? Googling for a solution is not easy - either i don't know proper words to describe the issue or Google tries to be smarter than me, and throws wrong answers at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a mistake in your reasoning which explains the problem and solution as well.

There are 2 alt keys on your keyboard. The Left Alt (normal alt) and the right alt (AltGr).

The AltGR is basically the same as CTRL-ALT on the left side.

If you use a keyboard language that adds specific language keys to the keyboard using AltGr, then you can no longer use the right AltGr for regular alt functions. The left Alt key is still unaffected though.

The solution to your problem is going to be one of the following two:

1. Use the left Alt
2. Switch to a language independend keyboard layout, such as United States.

It is also possible that switching to another program changes the keyboard layout to a language independend layout, and that it disables the AltGr functionality. In that case, you have to switch back to the language after starting the program.

Comment: Spot on. Was just going to say the same thing, right from the Q title. :)

Comment: Sadly left alt does not work with polish characters, only right one :/
But thx for pointing me in the right direction ;)